# Style 6 images to inline in a single row for desktop and responsiveness to mobile orientation

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

I want to display different sizes of images in rows. 6 images with proper margins for desktop, 2 images in a line for portrait and 4 images for landscape orientation. Extra images should be in a new line and aligned center.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="media-elements ">
        <div class="common-image">
            <figure class="figure">
                <img src="img1.png" class="img-fluid" alt="" title="">
                <figcaption class="figure-caption">
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media-elements ">
        <div class="common-image">
            <figure class="figure">
                <img src="img2.png" class="img-fluid" alt="" title="">
                <figcaption class="figure-caption">
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media-elements ">
        <div class="common-image">
            <figure class="figure">
                <img src="img3.png" class="img-fluid" alt="" title="">
                <figcaption class="figure-caption">
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media-elements ">
        <div class="common-image">
            <figure class="figure">
                <img src="img4.png" class="img-fluid" alt="" title="">
                <figcaption class="figure-caption">
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried **float: left** and **display:inline-block** but none of these give me expected results. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use a combination of flex and media query. I have compiled an example for you but you can further improve it.

```
.slider {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .slider {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
}
```

Please check the fiddle below.
https://jsfiddle.net/harsh89/x40kagm6/9/

Comment: Im not using a class called slider

Comment: @shen4 This is only an example, but the concept behind is correct, on my opinion. Moreover, Bootstrap4 has different classes to help you to manage Flexbox: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/. I think it could be a good way to resolve your problem.

Comment: hi Shen,
I am just using random class names. I have modified my earlier fiddle to your example. You can use the same CSS to your classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: grid`

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
}
figure img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y8pLs57g/

Comment: I didnt know about such a repeat function. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.figure {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}
.common-image::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```